# get all attributes value of div using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using this code for a single div

`<div ISBN ='978'></div>
    <div ISBN ='979'></div>
    <div ISBN ='974'></div>
    <div ISBN ='976'></div>`

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div").getAttribute("isbn");
```

i want to get all div ISBN values as 978,979,974,...etc

Comment: Use jQuery selector $('div[ISBN]')

Comment: You should really consider using `data-isbn` as your attribute name. `ISBN` is not a valid attribute in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var attr = [];
    var attr = Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem, function(e){
      attr.push(e.getAttribute("ISBN"));
    });
```

Now your array `attr` has all `ISBN` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var isbns = [];
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   isbns.push(divs[i].getAttribute("isbn"));
}
```

Now you have the numbers in the array named isbns